# DoCmd.OutputTo only works on break

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

I've come across a challenging problem with the DoCmd.OutputTo command in VBA Access 2013.

I've got below code which is basically to print a specific report from what is essentially a collection of records of reimbursements. The idea is that one would be able to [export] the active record (from the active form) to a PDF file and then add the scanned invoices to the PDF.

Thereto I would need to build the base file (i.e. the PDF where the invocies are added to) and then run the routine for adding the individual files.

Below code should create the initial PDF file:

```
    Dim rpt as Report

    filePath = "<some filepath>"
    fName = Me!idDecl & " - (script).pdf"
    filePath = filePath & fName

    Set rpt = Report_qryDeclInvoice
    With rpt
        .Filter = "[fltID]= " & Me!id
        .FilterOn = True
    End With

    DoCmd.OpenReport rpt.Name, acViewPreview, , "[fltID]= " & Me!id
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, rpt.Name, acFormatPDF, filePath, False
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "qryDeclInvoice"
```

If I run the code -without breaks- the report opens as per the filtered argument, however, the subsequent command to output the record to PDF doesn't ? 
That is, there appears a dialog box very briefly (can't read what it says) and then execution simply stops, no errors, no faultcodes just a clean break ?

Now for the interesting bit..
If I set a breakpoint on the DoCmd.OutputTo line, and execute the line with F8 the code works more or less flawlessly (see below)?? It appears that the break allows the preview routine to complete first and then run the OutputTo routine.

In addition to above challenge, on some of the reports (i.e. on some reimbursements) it works fine and the file is created yet on others it does not create the initial PDF at all and the code breaks without error codes or fault reporting. Without there being a distinguishable difference between the reports ?

I've tried delaying the OutputTo from the OpenReport function by sleeping it for 1000ms but that doesn't work (even upto 5000ms doesn't yield results)

Also if I remove the open preview line and just execute the OutputTo line, without opening the preview first, it works only when breaking and executing with F8 and again, only on some of the reports not all ?

It seems that the OutputTo command is -at least in my case- somewhat unreliable :-)

Any suggestions ??

Comment: GD All,

OK, found out what was going on;

The faulty reports created multiple pages, based on grouping.

VBA code in/on the report, re-created page numbers based on grouping (i.e. restarted page numbering for start of every group.)

The execution of VBA within the report (i.e. on open, or on page) interferes with the execution of OutputTo routine

Both the above interfered with the OutputTo routine, though not sure why -yet-

Removal of all VBA code within the report solved the issue !!

Comment: Excellent - why not add that as an answer, Q&A style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found out what was going on;

The faulty reports, that I mentioned, created multiple pages, based on grouping.

A section of VBA code in/on the report, re-created page numbers based on grouping (i.e. restarted page numbering for start of every group.) The execution of this VBA within the report (i.e. on open, or on page) interferes with the execution of the "OutputTo" routine. The above interfered with the OutputTo routine, causing it to break, though not sure why -yet-

Removal of all VBA code within the report solved the issue !!

Some added details:

- No need for the preview anymore
- set the filter of the report from VBA and open the report through the report object.name

Find below the working code:

```
Dim rpt as Report

filePath = "<somepath>"
fName = Me!idDecl & "-(script).pdf"
filePath = filePath & fName
'Debug.Print filePath

Set rpt = Report_qryInvoice
With rpt
    .Filter = "[fltID]= " & Me!id
    .FilterOn = True
End With

'Sleep (5000)
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, rpt.Name, acFormatPDF, filePath, False, , , acExportQualityScreen
```